# Angular ngx infinite scroll not detecting window scroll

Tags: angular

HTML -

```
<div class="search-results" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" (scrolled)="onScroll()" [scrollWindow]="true">
```

TS-

```
onScroll() {
  this.skip = this.skip + this.limit;
  if (this.totalCount > 2) {
    this.service.details(this.id, this.skip, this.limit, this.stime, this.etime)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.data = this.data.concat(res.data.data.rec);
          this.cd.detectChanges();
        },
        (error) => {
          this.cd.detectChanges();
        });
  }
}
```

Have imported "InfiniteScrollModule" in module and defined in TS as well.
When I give this div some height and apply overflow then it works.
But it is not working on window scroll.
It was working before but now i dont know what happened.
PS. I am new to angular.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, at least for the current version of the library you should use
**infinite-scroll** directive instead of **infiniteScroll**.
Maybe that's the reason.

Also, I would suggest preloading some data or using the flag
**immediateCheck**, because scroll event should be triggered on a div, so if nothing to scroll here, no event to be triggered.

UPD: Both selectors are fine as I see
"[infiniteScroll], [infinite-scroll], [data-infinite-scroll]"